# How to get $a$ from $2 = \log_{5/4}a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not know what algebra to apply to get $a$ values from
$2 = \log_{5/4}a$

I will appreciate you help!

Comment: Try proving that $$\log_aX=\frac{\log_bX}{\log_ba}$$
Hint
$$X=a^{\log_{a}X}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert from log form to exponential form.

The first equation becomes $${(\frac{5}{4})}^2=a$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$\log_b a = c$ is the same thing as saying $a = b^c$!